# How to read console.log on the terminal using parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, console, console.log

I am new using cloud code of parse.com

I am trying to debug my cloud code, but I can not read the console.log in the terminal. I am using the console of my Mac in this way:

> parse deploy

Once the code has update successfully, I curl -X POST the code of the app (the function I want to test) but I can only read the response.success() or the response.error(), all the console.log that I have in the code doesn't appear in the console.

I assume that the log output should appear in the console, but it doesn't.

Comment: I got an answer my self: just need to read the log: parse log

Comment: NB actually `parse logs` with an "s".  As explained below `parse develop ...` is often more useful. salud!

Comment: Just a note, Parse.com is closing at the end of 2016, so I wouldn't worry about it too much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*note* for anyone reading, Parse.com is closing down later in 2016 - so don't get too invested in it  :O

consider say back4app.com

If you're reading this in the far future .. Parse.com was an ingenious BAAS which ran for a couple years, sensibly sold out to Facebook, and then FB gave up after a couple years. It was basically free to use, so the whole fiasco maybe marks the end of the "amazing stuff, totally free to developers" era.

---

In your Terminal it's

> ] parse logs

to see the last few logs.

or if you want to watch everything continuously from the cloud,

they have a command which pipes that output continuously to your terminal:

> ] parse develop "Your App Name"

So as you, or indeed normal users of your app, uses the Parse app, you can watch **"everything that is happening"**.

(Note too that, once you "turn on" the "parse develop" mode: as well as printing out everything that is happening on the server, additionally: if you locally edit the text files (main.js and so on) in fact, it goes ahead and uploads them to the server, **that is to say, just as if you had done a "parse deploy"**.)

This is a good question -- it's really quite astounding that this is so badly explained everywhere, since, Parse is completely unusable unless you know about these two commands!!

Comment: Just a quick addition: "parse develop yourAppName" will upload new files as mentioned by @joe-blow. To only tail the logs you can run: "parse logs -f yourAppName", which will output the logs in realtime to your terminal without watching for new file uploads. I find it helpful to run "parse deploy yourAppName && parse logs -f yourAppName", which allows you to deploy once then tail the logs

Comment: OUTSTANDING tip, liamp.  I'm glad there's a way to "turn off" the auto-uploading.